# How can I Segment Breast with polynomail curve fitting and circle fitting algorithm to get segmented/seperated left and right breast?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, image-segmentation

I am studying on breast thermogram for early detection of breast cancer in MATLAB. But I could not segment and seperate each breast.I tried second polynomial curve fitting algoritm but it didn't work. Inferior lateral quadrant should be inclueded in its entirely regardless of breast size because the algorithm should be for different breasts and breast size. My purpose and desire is to seperate left and rigt breast automatically for bilateral asymmetry analysis.

You can see below what I desire.

[Breast Thermogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPgKe.jpg) // Original Pic.
[image]

[Detection 4 curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8WcG.png) // Detected 4 curves of breast
[image]

[Curve fitting,circle fitting and seperated breast as left and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om1y2.png) // Subfigures (b) and (c) show my desire.

**Conditions of detecting 4 curves of breast, circle fitting and breast region:**

- Since the breast boundaries are parabolic in shape, a 2nd order polynomial fitting
  algorithm was used to detect the bottom breast boundaries. A parabolic curve was first fitted
  to each object, then two curves with maximum coefficient of determination candidate
  for the lower breast boundaries. If the difference between x-coordinates of the lowest
  peaks of two curves was less than 20 and the difference of their y-coordinates was greater
  than 250, they were selected as lower breast boundaries (X–X ′ < 20 and Y–Y ′ > 250).
  Otherwise, the algorithm searched the other curves.
- The next step is to determine the top of the breast. In Qi and co-workers [19,21]
  study, the region with the highest curvature in the left and right body edges was used
  to estimate the position of the armpit. Often, poor edge detection indicated major points
  of concavity elsewhere in the body edge, and the point of maximum concavity in the
  image was found to be lower or higher than what was expected. Besides, choosing the
  fitted parabola as lower breast boundaries may be lead to crop the region of the breast
  and cause information loss because of the poor lower breast edge in many cases.
- This work proposed to fit a circle to each lower edge object for delimiting
  the breasts in the region of the breasts in the image. The circle-fitting algorithm
  was taken from Kasa method [22]. The same procedure was repeated for both sides.
- After detection of the breast regions, a middle separation line was created to separate
  between left and right segments along the point of contact of the two breast curves.

Could you please help me about my problem? I'm looking forward to hearing from u. Thanks in advance.

```
clc; clear; close all;
a=rgb2gray(imread('DINAMIC-FRONTAL.jpg'));
en= imsharpen(a,'Radius',2,'Amount',1);
B = imgaussfilt(en,1.4);
ed=edge(B,'canny',0.3,0.5);
figure();imshow(ed);title('canny edge');
bw1=bwareaopen(ed,10);
se = strel('disk',4);
bw=imdilate(bw1,se);
figure();imshow(bw);
[y x] = find( bw );
right = find(min(a));
as=findpeaks(y);
xr = x(right);
yr = y(right);
xl = x(as);
yl = y(as);
pr = polyfit( yr, xr, 2);  %// fit 2rd deg poly
pl = polyfit( yl, xl, 2 ); 
yy = linspace( 1, size(bw,1), 50 );
figure; imshow(a, 'border', 'tight' );
hold all
plot( polyval( pr, yy ), yy, '.-', 'LineWidth', 1 );
plot( polyval( pl, yy ), yy, '.-', 'LineWidth', 1 );
```

Comment: Hi CANSU, welcome on Stack Overflow! It is unclear to me what's your question exactly. Is your script generating a "wrong" result? Or is your script throwing an error somewhere? Or something else?

Comment: My question is how can i segment the breast as left and right. My code includes polynomial curve fitting but i couldn’t find the lowest peaks of two curves (lower breast boundaries)and their X and Y coordinates of which conditions are X1-X2<20 and Y1-Y2>250. Also i need to find the top of the breast with the highest curvature in the right and left body edges should be used to estimate position of armpit. You can see this in the pic. of which name is Detection 4 Curves.

Comment: Hi Matteo, could you please help me for this problem. At least how to detect lower breast boundaries(left and right) with polynomial curve fitting